# file name image upload

Tags: php

When I upload image filename contain "two words.jpg" (there a white space in the middle). It will not echo an error message. Does anyone have the same issue?

PHP:

```
$file = $_FILES['Filedata'];
if ($file["size"] > 20000) {echo "Excess limit size"; die('EXCESS');}
```

Comment: Part of the code will be AS3. It is fine if I upload "filename.jpg" that has no whilespace.

Comment: Can you show the error message then, and the line that's causing it? And I assume your PHP code does some more stuff than what you show above? Like, move the image to a new location or something?

Comment: ...and ask your question too. It isn't expected to throw any errors whatever the uploaded local file name was. Do you want to strip spaces from the name when uploading? Or is there some filename-checking code that you don't show us?

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbq="\"";
$filename=$dbq.'hello there.jpg'.$dbq;
echo( $filename );
```

Check this out it will make double quotes (or single one if you like) part of the file name.

This outputs: "hello there.jpg";

You have no other option use quotes  or strreplace quotes might be a bit faster I guess!

And you totally need quotes when file name contains spaces!!